# Google Charts: Registering a click on a GeoChart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, wrapper

I've been working on a small project to make a map of, in this case The Netherlands, with a bunch of markers on it. The data is provided through a CSV and i've linked the chart and a slider through a dashboard.

It's worked perfectly so far, however i'm having issues on the next functionality: Registering a click on a marker and then referring the user to a different webpage depending on which marker was clicked.

I've tried many times to get it to work, but i believe it has something to do with the fact that i'm using chartWrappers instead of a normal chart.

Here is my current code:

```
 google.charts.load('current', {
   'packages':['geochart', 'controls'],
   });
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

   function drawMarkersMap() {
      $.get("output.csv", function(csvString) {
         var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData)
         var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('controls_div'));

         var Slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
            containerId: 'controls_div',
            options: {
                filterColumnLabel: data.getColumnLabel(1)
            } 
          });

         var GeoChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'GeoChart',
            containerId: 'chart_div',
            options: {
                region: 'NL',
                displayMode: 'markers',
                resolution: 'provinces',
                colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
            }
          });

          google.visualization.events.addListener(GeoChart, 'select', function() {
          var selection = GeoChart.getChart().getSelection();
          //Above line doesn't work. Console also returns that getSelection property is null.
         });

         dashboard.bind(Slider, GeoChart);

         dashboard.draw(data);

    })};
```

If anyone with experience could help me properly set up a working listener i'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were right about wrapper vs. regular

the chart wrapper does not have an event for `'select'`

you have to wait until the wrapper is `'ready'`,
then listen for `'select'` on the chart,
see following snippet...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(GeoChart, 'ready', function() {
  google.visualization.events.addListener(GeoChart.getChart(), 'select', function() {
    var selection = GeoChart.getChart().getSelection();
  });
});
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['controls', 'geochart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity', 'Domain'],
    ['England', 400, 'www.example.com/England'],
    ['Wales', 300, 'www.example.com/Wales'],
    ['Scotland', 400, 'www.example.com/Scotland'],
    ['Ireland', 600, 'www.example.com/Ireland'],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1]);

  var GeoChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'GeoChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: view,
    options: {
      region: 'GB',
      displayMode: 'markers',
      resolution: 'provinces',
      colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(GeoChart, 'ready', function () {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(GeoChart.getChart(), 'select', function () {
      var selection = GeoChart.getChart().getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        console.log(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2));
        //window.open('http://' + data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2), '_blank');
      }
    });
  });

  GeoChart.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment. I sadly can't get it to work still. Even though i've applied your code it still gives a single error when clicking on a marker:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of null. This happens whenever i click on a marker. Doesn't matter if there's a listener for the click or not, even if that is removed completely, this error still occurs causing it to not execute any code.

Comment: added working example above, edit question with latest version of code, if needed...

Comment: Wanted to add that i've fixed the issue. Because of the huge set of data i'm using the chart took a while to load. This caused the ready event to never be fired, which is the reason getSelection was returning null.